# UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter Never Detected in viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am having a problem where the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` delegate function never detect `UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter`.

So, the headers are created, but the footer is never created.

I have also implemented both delegate `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` and `referenceSizeForFooterInSection` method.

I have registered the NIB too.

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "FooterCollectionReusableView", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "footerIdentifier");
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "HeaderCollectionReusableView", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerIdentifier");
```

Here is the code that is not working.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    var view: UICollectionReusableView! = UICollectionReusableView();
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
        print("HEADER DETECTED");//CALLED
        break;
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
        print("FOOTER DETECTED");//NEVER CALLED
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return view;
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

P.S.: I have read some people said that setting the `footerReferenceSize` in the `collectionView`'s layout would work, but I tried and it does not work either

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have an implementation for

```swift
func collectionView(
  _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
  referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int
) -> CGSize
```

Also, this function should return a non-zero size. I found that if by any chance zero dimensions are returned, UIKit will infer that no footer needs to de dequeued and won't call your `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` function, or `supplementaryViewProvider` if you're using diffable data sources introduced in iOS 13.